# Query Optimization to reduce multiple joins statements

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC
(
     key NUMBER(5), 
     orders NUMBER(5), 
     cost NUMBER(5), 
     dat DATE
);

insert into ABC (key, orders, cost, dat) values (1, 3, 5, to_date('10-11- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy'));
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 5, 2, to_date('02-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 6, 1, to_date('03-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy'));
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 7, 2, to_date('05-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 8, 3, to_date('07-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 3, 4, to_date('08-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 3, 6, to_date('02-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 3, 9, to_date('01-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 2 ,5, to_date('03-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 3, 2, to_date('05-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 1, 1, to_date('06-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 4, 12, to_date('10-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 3, 9, to_date('01-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 2 ,5, to_date('05-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 3, 2, to_date('06-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 1, 1, to_date('07-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 4, 12, to_date('11-10- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost, dat) values (1, 3, 5, to_date('10-01- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy'));
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 5, 2, to_date('02-17- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 6, 1, to_date('03-18- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy'));
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 7, 2, to_date('05-14- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 8, 3, to_date('07-13- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (1, 3, 4, to_date('08-12- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 3, 6, to_date('02-11- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 3, 9, to_date('01-15- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 2 ,5, to_date('03-14- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 3, 2, to_date('05-18- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (2, 1, 1, to_date('06-19- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 4, 12, to_date('10-11- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 3, 9, to_date('01-12- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 2 ,5, to_date('05-16- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 3, 2, to_date('06-17- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 1, 1, to_date('07-12- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 
insert into ABC (key, orders, cost,dat) values (3, 4, 12, to_date('12-21- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy'));
```

Not sure why my results are repeating.

Here is my query:

```
with qone as
(select a.key, a.max_price, max(t.dat) as qo_dat from  ABC t
JOIN
(select key, max(cost) as max_price from ABC
where dat >= to_date('01-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('04-01- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
group by key) a on a.key = t.key and a.max_price = t.cost
group by a.key, a.max_price),
qtwo as
(select a.key, a.max_price, max(t.dat) as qt_dat from  ABC t
JOIN
(select key, max(cost) as max_price from ABC
where dat >= to_date('04-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('07-01- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
group by key) a on a.key = t.key and a.max_price = t.cost
group by a.key, a.max_price),
qthree as
(select a.key, a.max_price, max(t.dat) as qth_dat from  ABC t
JOIN
(select key, max(cost) as max_price from ABC
where dat >= to_date('07-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('10-01- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
group by key) a on a.key = t.key and a.max_price = t.cost
group by a.key, a.max_price),
qfour as
(select a.key, a.max_price, max(t.dat) as qf_dat from  ABC t
JOIN
(select key, max(cost) as max_price from ABC
where dat >= to_date('10-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('01-01- 
2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
group by key) a on a.key = t.key and a.max_price = t.cost
group by a.key, a.max_price)
select qo.key, qo.max_price as max_q1, qo.qo_dat, qt.max_price as max_q2, 
qt.qt_dat, qth.max_price as max_q3, qth.qth_dat, qf.max_price as max_q4, 
qf.qf_dat from qone qo
join qtwo qt on qt.key = qo.key 
join qthree qth on qth.key = qth.key
join qfour qf on qf.key = qf.key
order by keyenter code here
```

I want to know if there is a way to reduce the lines.

How I did it? I find the Max Price and Max Date for each quarter, I define the quarters using where statement.

I use Divide and Conquer technique, I find the Max price and the respective date for all four quarters and join them on the key. Sample of one self-defined quarter below.

```
`select a.key, a.max_price, max(t.dat) as qo_dat from  ABC t
JOIN
(select key, max(cost) as max_price from ABC
where dat >= to_date('01-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('04-01- 
2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
group by key) a on a.key = t.key and a.max_price = t.cost
group by a.key, a.max_price`
```

Output:

[image: where]

Possible optimized solution: but I m figuring out a way to add a corresponding date next to it

```
select 
    t.key, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q1From and t.dat < Tmp.Q1End then t.cost 
else 0 end ) as Q1Tot, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q1End and t.dat < Tmp.Q2End then t.cost else 
0 end ) as Q2Tot, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q2End and t.dat < Tmp.Q3End then t.cost else 
0 end ) as Q3Tot, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q3End and t.dat < Tmp.Q4End then t.cost else 
0 end ) as Q4Tot 
from 
    ABC t,
       ( select 
               to_date('01-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q1From,
               to_date('04-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q1End,
               to_date('07-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q2End,
               to_date('10-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q3End,
               to_date('01-01-2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q4End
            from 
               dual ) Tmp
 where 
        t.dat >= to_date('01-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    and t.dat < to_date('01-01-2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
 group by 
    t.key
```

Comment: SQL FIDDLE IS HERE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01217/33

Comment: Man, hate to tell You, however noone is gonna read upper query. Quite insane. Possibly abstract what You want to do with which data.

Comment: There are 4 queries joined with each other, The only difference is that the where clause is selecting different dates. I want to know if the number of lines and performance can be reduced.

Comment: I would use a single CTE grouping also by quarter (function `TO_CHAR(date_field, 'Q')`.

Comment: Just a note. Your query returns the **LAST DATE** when the price reached its peak. If there are multiple date, it will only show the last one. Just saying.

Comment: Yes @The Impaler, that's the plan. To get the latest date. Fixed the multiple date problem on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using JOINs or cross joins, consider using the analytical function NTH_VALUE (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NTH_VALUE.html#GUID-F8A0E88C-67E5-4AA6-9515-95D03A7F9EA0)) for displaying the required values for the 4 quarters side by side.

> NTH_VALUE returns the measure_expr value of the nth row in the window
>   defined by the analytic_clause.

First step: find the "max costs" and their corresponding dates for all keys (and quarters).

```
select *
from (
  select key, dat, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) quarter 
  , max( cost ) over ( partition by key, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) order by cost desc ) maxcost_
  , max( dat ) over ( partition by key, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) order by cost desc ) maxdat_
  , row_number()  over ( partition by key, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) order by cost desc ) rownum_
    from abc
)
where rownum_ = 1 

-- result
KEY  DAT        QUARTER  MAXCOST_  MAXDAT_    ROWNUM_  
1    17-FEB-17  1        2         17-FEB-17  1        
1    14-MAY-17  2        2         14-MAY-17  1        
1    12-AUG-17  3        4         12-AUG-17  1        
1    01-OCT-17  4        5         11-OCT-17  1        
2    10-JAN-17  1        9         15-JAN-17  1        
2    10-MAY-17  2        2         18-MAY-17  1        
3    10-JAN-17  1        9         12-JAN-17  1        
3    10-MAY-17  2        5         16-MAY-17  1        
3    10-JUL-17  3        1         12-JUL-17  1        
3    10-NOV-17  4        12        21-DEC-17  1        

10 rows selected.
```

Final query: use the first query as an INLINE VIEW, and call NTH_VALUE for retrieving the values for each quarter.

```
select unique key
,  nth_value( maxcost_, 1 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q1max
,  nth_value( maxdat_, 1 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q1date
,  nth_value( maxcost_, 2 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q2max
,  nth_value( maxdat_, 2 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q2date
,  nth_value( maxcost_, 3 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q3max
,  nth_value( maxdat_, 3 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q3date
,  nth_value( maxcost_, 4 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q4max
,  nth_value( maxdat_, 4 ) from first over ( partition by key ) q4date
from (
  select *
  from ( 
    select key, dat, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) quarter 
    , max( cost ) over ( partition by key, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) order by cost desc ) maxcost_
    , max( dat ) over ( partition by key, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) order by cost desc ) maxdat_
    , row_number()  over ( partition by key, to_char( dat, 'Q' ) order by cost desc ) rownum_
    from abc
  )
  where rownum_ = 1  
) -- inline view (no name required)
order by key
;

-- result
KEY  Q1MAX  Q1DATE     Q2MAX  Q2DATE     Q3MAX  Q3DATE     Q4MAX  Q4DATE     
1    2      17-FEB-17  2      14-MAY-17  4      12-AUG-17  5      11-OCT-17  
2    9      15-JAN-17  2      18-MAY-17  NULL   NULL       NULL   NULL       
3    9      12-JAN-17  5      16-MAY-17  1      12-JUL-17  12     21-DEC-17
```

Comment: What is 'over' function doing? Partition is similar to group by right?

Comment: According to the documentation (eg https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056), OVER() is the "analytic clause" used in an "analytic function".  PARTITION BY creates a so-called sliding window.  One of the differences to GROUP BY is: you'll get multiple values for each group - that's why we've used SELECT UNIQUE ... for getting the final result.

Comment: how do you go about this when doing monthly? I've tried `to_char(dat, 'MM')` and have used `nth_value(max_cost,1) ... to ... nth_value(max_cost,12)`?

Comment: I'd probably DENSIFY the data first (using a PARTITION BY outer join), and then apply the N_TH value.  I've written an example for you, see  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b8917caeff3fea123b38cf6f1b31938

Comment: Thanks, Stefan, That's a fast technique.

Comment: I m trying to do the same for Years and Month, I figured out a way to join Years and Months. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=92a9f675ac2947185cb788876624e57d

Comment: Now I need to select from the above, for Year first then months.

Comment: For this I recommend: find all month/year combinations (always use 4 digits for years!), then use the PARTITION BY ... RIGHT JOIN.  This will give you rows for each month/year.  See (last query @ ) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78f62687846351ab8e5a99bf54c6a201

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could rewrite it in a shorter way, as in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01217/41):

```
select a.key, qtr, a.max_price, max(t.dat) as qo_dat 
from ABC t
join (
  select key, to_char(dat, 'Q') as qtr, max(cost) as max_price 
  from ABC
  where dat >= to_date('01-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
    and dat < to_date('01-01-2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
  group by key, to_char(dat, 'Q')
) a on a.key = t.key and a.max_price = t.cost and a.qtr = to_char(t.dat, 'Q')
group by a.key, a.qtr, a.max_price
order by a.key, a.qtr, a.max_price
```

The output is a little bit different, but it shows what you want. Doesn't it?

Comment: Nice answer, but I need the date and the format as shown in the question because I will be adding other columns to this result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.key, a.q1tot, b.dat, a.q2tot, c.dat, a.q3tot, d.dat, a.q4tot, e.dat from (
select 
    t.key, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q1From and t.dat < Tmp.Q1End then t.cost else 0 end ) as Q1Tot, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q1End and t.dat < Tmp.Q2End then t.cost else 0 end ) as Q2Tot, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q2End and t.dat < Tmp.Q3End then t.cost else 0 end ) as Q3Tot, 
    max( case when t.dat >= Tmp.Q3End and t.dat < Tmp.Q4End then t.cost else 0 end ) as Q4Tot 
from 
    ABC t,
       ( select 
               to_date('01-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q1From,
               to_date('04-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q1End,
               to_date('07-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q2End,
               to_date('10-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q3End,
               to_date('01-01-2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy') Q4End
            from 
               dual ) Tmp
 where 
        t.dat >= to_date('01-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    and t.dat < to_date('01-01-2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
 group by 
    t.key) a
    join 
 ( select key, cost, dat from ABC
  where dat < to_date('04-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy')) b
  on a.key = b.key and a.Q1tot = b.cost
  join
  ( select key, cost, dat from ABC
   where dat >= to_date('04-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('07-01-2017', 
'mm-dd-yyyy')) c
 on a.key = c.key and a.Q1tot = c.cost
 join
 ( select key, cost, dat  from ABC
  where dat >= to_date('07-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('10-01-2017', 
'mm-dd-yyyy')) d
 on a.key = d.key and a.Q1tot = d.cost
    join
 ( select key, cost, dat from ABC
  where dat >= to_date('10-01-2017', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and dat < to_date('01-01-2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy')) e
  on a.key = e.key and a.Q1tot = e.cost
```

This is my code, But the above two queries perform faster